# How to search based on Rest API data?

Tags: rest, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've created Rest API, connected to Ionic app successfully and displayed data.

home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let item of allProducts">
        {{item.title}}
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

home.ts

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
    this.productProvider.getProduct()
        .subscribe(productList=> this.allProducts=productList);
}
```

API has example data like below, product titles like below:

> abc
>   xyz
>   rmn
>   zxy

My question is:

In search bar, if I give `abc` and then enter, it should display that particular product.

How can I do this? I tried `<ion-searchbar>` but it is not working.
Could any one tell me how to do this? Or is there any tutorial for my case?

Comment: Try this guide: https://www.joshmorony.com/high-performance-list-filtering-in-ionic-2/

Comment: Are you FILTERING or SEARCHING?  Filter meaning you already got data, and you need to show/hide based on input.  Search meaning you need to go hit the API based on user search terms.

Comment: @BRass, based on his question, he is trying search data which has data in API

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>

getItems(event) {
  let search = event.target.value;

  if (search && search.trim() != '') {

    this.productProvider.getProduct(search).subscribe((products) => {
      console.dir(products);
    }, (err) => {
       console.log(err);
    });
  } 
}
```

You can use ionInput event to send search based api request